# toast is displayed before getting GPS location

Tags: android

When I press the button to start getting the location , immediately the toast message comes up and shows  lat:0  lon:0  (the initialized values).

After a few seconds I must press again the button to get location and then it shows the location.

What can I do for that?

(As I understand , if I use delay it doesn't solve the problem.I want the toast message to wait until I get the location)

```
 if(gps.canGetLocation()){

 latitude = gps.getLatitude();
 longitude = gps.getLongitude();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is  \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    ...
```

I used sth like:

```
 private void showToast() {
               new Thread() {
                   public void run() {
                    try {   
                       while (message) {
                           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                           if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                                latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    longitude = gps.getLongitude();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                 message=false;
                                  }else{

                                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                                }
                           });
                           Thread.sleep(1000);
                       } 
                   }   catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                   }
                   }
               }.start();
               }
```

But it doesn't seem to work.Also ,is there a way to show another message until the location is found?

Comment: Use `AsyncTask` and display the `Toast` in `onPostExecute()`. Or use a `runnable` to get the location and display it in `runOnUiThread()`

Comment: why cant you just use a simple boolean or check to see if the lat/lng is 0? if it is 0 just say location not established yet

Comment: @tyczj that would keep from showing "0" in the `Toast` but won't ever show the location if its not in a `loop, timer, AsyncTask` or something to keep checking

Comment: @codeMagic:I updated my post.I used runnable but it doesn't seem to get location..

Comment: I was in the middle of posting an answer when you updated. I will take a look but I think `AsymcTask` might still be better if you have any thoughts of modifying it or reusing it

Comment: `while(true)` will give you an infinite loop. You need a `boolean flag` to change to false when you get the data. You can use a `Progress Dialog`

Answer (score 0):

As codeMagic said, use a diffrent thead to keep checking. GPS needs time to get a fix.

Maybe you can look into a `Service` which manages the GPS fix while your app is running.

Answer (score 0):

For something like this it would probably be best to use an `AsyncTask`, IMHO. This will allow it to be more versatile and portable in case you want to use it in another `Actviity` or application. Here is a quick example of how it could work

```
public class GetGPSData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
//do your work here
  if(gps.canGetLocation())
        {
             latitude = gps.getLatitude();
             longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        }
while (latitude == 0 || longitude ==0)
{

    Thread.sleep(300);  // let the background thread sleep 
}
 return something;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
       // do something with data here-display it or send to mainactivity
Toast.makeText(context, "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Some of it may need to be modified depending on where you put it and what you do with it but something like this would work. You could also show a `progress dialog` while getting the data so the user knows it is loading

**Edit**

This was just a rough example. You can change the params as you need. `doInBackground()` can take no `params`. Just change it to

```
Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
```

and change your class declaration to

```
extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
```

And you don't call the method directly. You do something like

```
GetGPSData gps = new GetGPSData();   could send params to a constructor if you needed
gps.execute();  // could put params here if you needed for doInBackground()
```

Be sure to look through the [AsyncTask Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) there is information that you need to understand about them but once you get it, life is a lot easier.

Comment: :Ok, inside "while" I am trying sth like "ToastMessage=params[0];
   params[0]=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wait for location to be established " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();return params[0]".(I declared String ToastMessage) but i am receiving "Cannot convert from void to string".And finally ,how should I call the doInBackground method ?Because it takes String as argument.

Comment: I have updated my post. Also, you don't use `Toast` in `doInBackground()` as it runs on the `UI` thread and that's a no no. Do it in `onPostExecute()` or one of the other methods

Comment: :The only error now is in " protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {".It says "Multiple markers at this line
 - implements 
  android.os.AsyncTask<java.lang.Void,java.lang.Void,java.lang.String>.doInBackground
 - The return type is incompatible with AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>.doInBackground(Void[])". (I used Void,Void,String)

Comment: The last `param` in `extends ...<Void, Void, String>` is what your `onPostExecute()` takes. If you want it to take a `String` then leave it and change the return `String doInBackground(Void...params)` and `return yourString` in `doInBackground()`

Comment: :Wait.In onPostExecute(String result) I have the toast message.In doInBackground I have the code (without returning anything because I don't want (and it is void))

Comment: I assume you know some Java. If you have `onPostExecute(String result)` that is expecting to have  a `String` result passed to it. The result of `doInBackground()` is sent to it. If you don't want to return anything to it then you don't have to but you have to change it to `onPostExecute(Void result)` so it doesn't expect anything. And `return null` in `doInBackground()`

Comment: They basically work like any other methods in that way. But they can take `vargs` and they have a certain sequence of what calls what

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29419/discussion-between-george-and-codemagic)